# Calculating Percentage with for loop with a group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have the below code with loop that gives me the ratio of lost and won types based on below, how would I alter code if I want to look at same data but grouped by professor?

```
leads = ['Passed','Failed']
max_status = None
max_percent = None
for lead in leads:
    df_overall = df[(df['Status']== lead) & (df['size']== '20-34')]
    num_overall = len(df_overall) 
    lead_df = df[(df['size']== '20-34')]
    num_total = len(lead_df)
    percentage_overall = num_overall / num_total
   
    
    if max_status is None: 
        
        
        
        print(lead, percentage_overall)
```

This gives me output as below:

```
Passed .65
Failed .35
```

I want to edit code where I have it broken out by grouped by professor since their is a professor column in my dataframe as well.

Expected Output:

```
Mr. Johnson Passed .35
Mr. Johnson Failed .65
Ms. Jones   Passed .90
Ms. Jones   Failed .10
Mr. Boe     Passed .80
Mr. Boe     Passed .20
```

Thanks

Comment: You `groupby` professor, and then apply your math to each group.  There are plenty of examples in on-line tutorials.  Where are you stuck?  Please post your coding attempt.

Comment: can you share some of the contents from df. I think you can do this with a simpler groupby

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
leads = ['Passed','Failed']

lead_df = df[(df['size']== '20-34')]
#filter by list leads
df_overall = lead_df[lead_df['Status'].isin(lead)]

num_overall1 = df_overall.groupby(['professor','Status']).size()
num_total1 = lead_df.groupby(['professor','Status']).size()

out = num_overall1.div(num_total1).reset_index(name='per')
print (out)
```